# Operations over a a Stored Procedure table SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Can I do operations (SUM, AVG etc.) on a table returned from a Stored Procedure in T-SQL?

Here my SP code:

```
exec CC_SP_ReadTags
   '11', '2016-12-07 00:00:00', '2016-12-07 23:00:00','','Timestamp ASC','TIMESTEP=60,2'
```

With this I get this table:

[image]

The data stored in the field RealValue are varchar and I would like to do the AVG on them, is it possible in some way?
I have tried all these commands but without success:

```
select AVG(RealValue)

SELECT CAST(RealValue AS INT)

SELECT CONVERT(INT, RealValue)
```

Any help is appreciated thank you all.

Here is the SP code:

```
USE CC_SIR_16_07_29_11_30_35R
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO


CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CC_SP_ReadTags]
(
    @List varchar(1000),
    @TimeBegin varchar(32),
    @TimeEnd varchar(32),
    @WHEREClause varchar(1000)= NULL,
    @ORDERBYClause varchar(1000) = NULL,
    @Timestep varchar(500) = NULL,
    @Aggregationmode int = 0,
    @SymDataSource varchar(512) = NULL,
    @SymCatalog varchar(512) = NULL,
    @LS_Name varchar(255)=NULL
)
WITH encryption
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    --DECLARE @LS_Name varchar(255)
    DECLARE @Catalogname varchar(255)   
    DECLARE @Internal_LS bit
    DECLARE @NoTime bit
    SET @Internal_LS = 0

    -- check valid datetime or Aggregationmode = 0
    DECLARE @ret int
    SET @ret = ISDATE(@TimeBegin)
    IF (@ret = 0 and @Aggregationmode <> 0)
        RETURN

    IF ISNULL(@LS_Name,'') = ''
    BEGIN
        SET @LS_Name = 'CA_'+ CAST(@@SPID as varchar(10))
        SET @Catalogname = DB_NAME()
        if @SymDataSource = NULL
            set @SymDataSource = 'Hallo'
        if ISNULL(@SymDataSource,'') = '' or ISNULL(@SymCatalog,'') = ''
        BEGIN
            EXEC sp_addlinkedserver @server = @LS_Name,@srvproduct = 'CommonArchiving',  @provider = 'WinCCOLEDBProvider', @datasrc = @@servername, @catalog =  @CatalogName 
            set @Internal_LS = 1
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            EXEC sp_addlinkedserver @server = @LS_Name,@srvproduct = 'CommonArchiving',  @provider = 'WinCCOLEDBProvider', @datasrc = @SymDataSource, @catalog =  @SymCatalog 
            set @Internal_LS = 1
        END
  END

    DECLARE @Statement varchar(8000)
    SET @Statement = ''

    SET @Statement = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY('+@LS_Name+',''Tag:R,('+@List+'),'''''+@TimeBegin+''''','''''+@TimeEnd+''''''

    IF(LEN(@TimeStep) <> 0)
    BEGIN
     SET @Statement = @Statement + ',' + @Timestep + ',' + CAST(@Aggregationmode AS VARCHAR(6))
    END

    SET @Statement = @Statement + ' '') '

    IF(LEN(@WHEREClause) <> 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @Statement = @Statement + @WHEREClause
    END

    IF(LEN(@ORDERBYClause) <> 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @Statement = @Statement + ' ORDER BY ' + @ORDERBYClause
    END

    --print @Statement

    BEGIN
        EXEC( @Statement )
    END

    if @Internal_LS = 1
    BEGIN
        EXEC sp_dropserver @server = @LS_Name
        set @LS_Name = NULL
    END
    SET NOCOUNT OFF
END

GO
```

Comment: Why do you want an `Int`? Wouldn't you want to use `Decimal` in this case?

Comment: Yes also Decimal is fine but it is not working as well

Comment: I've given you an example with decimal.

Comment: What happens when you run those select commands that don't work?

Comment: The error message is: Invalid column name 'RealValue'. And when I create a temp table to store the values, it doesnt insert values because of that one timestamp field, which doesn't allow to copy value in it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example...

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE  (RealValue NVARCHAR(50))
INSERT @tbl
         ( RealValue )
VALUES   ( N'0'), ( N'15.321'), ( N'9.854')

SELECT AVG(CAST(RealValue AS DECIMAL(18,8))) FROM @tbl
```

You'll need to populate a *temp* table from your stored procedure, and then cast the `RealValue` before calling `AVG`.

```
INSERT INTO #Temp_CC_SP_ReadTags
exec CC_SP_ReadTags
   '11', '2016-12-07 00:00:00', '2016-12-07 23:00:00','','Timestamp ASC','TIMESTEP=60,2'

SELECT AVG(CAST(RealValue AS DECIMAL(18,13))) FROM #Temp_CC_SP_ReadTags
```

Obviously, set the decimal to the [precision and scale](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms190476.aspx) you need.

> Precision is the number of digits in a number. Scale is the number of
>   digits to the right of the decimal point in a number. For example, the
>   number 123.45 has a precision of 5 and a scale of 2.

Comment: I'm using your example but i have this error already: Cannot insert an explicit value into a timestamp column. Use INSERT with a column list to exclude the timestamp column, or insert a DEFAULT into the timestamp column.

Comment: Are you building the temp table with `DateStamp`? if so, change that to `DateTime`

Comment: I am building the temp table with TimeStamp, if I try with DateTime is not working either

Comment: If I create the table with any other data type different than timestamp: Msg 15002, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_addlinkedserver, Line 53
The procedure 'sys.sp_addlinkedserver' cannot be executed within a transaction.
Msg 7202, Level 11, State 2, Line 1
Could not find server 'CA_77' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.
Msg 15002, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_dropserver, Line 12
The procedure 'sys.sp_dropserver' cannot be executed within a transaction.

Comment: Is it possible to insert in the temp table just the RealValue field?

Comment: Those issues are within the Stored Proc you're calling.  Can you show the content of the SP? `CC_SP_ReadTags`

Comment: This question is evolving with time! The answer I gave answers the initial question, but the other errors are internal to this SP.  Also, you cant use...`if @SymDataSource = NULL`, is should be `IS NULL`

Comment: The problem now is that the internal SP is encrypted and I don't think I am going to change it. I think I will put the results of the SP into a gridview and then I will do operations on that, is this reasonable?

Answer (score 0):

you can store table returned by stored procedure into temporary table

```
    create table #temp(
    ValueId int,
    [Timestamp] timestamp,
    Realvalue varchar(250),
    quality int,
    flags int
    )
    insert into #temp
    exec CC_SP_ReadTags
    '11', '2016-12-07 00:00:00', '2016-12-07 23:00:00','','Timestamp      ASC','TIMESTEP=60,2'
```

then you can use query on that table